# Google App Engine: Fastest way to get a large collection of objects from Keys using objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a large (about 20000) objects that I want to retrieve based on user IDs contained in AlertSubscription. This takes 20+ seconds on GAE and I wonder if it is possible to get this faster? I have already retrieved 20000 AlertSubscriptions objects in 5 seconds using a standard Query so I think it's strange that the DeviceInfo objects should take 20+ seconds.

My current logic is as follows:

1. Get list of alert subscriptions
2. Get all the DeviceInfo tied to the subscriptions
3. Start one task for each OS (Android, iOS, WP7/8)

Therefore I need all the devices in one go so using a Cursor wouldn't help much. Is there a way to add a index to the Key of the object to make this go faster? I have no indexes setup in the datastore-index.xml file.

```
    List<com.googlecode.objectify.Key<DeviceInfo>> dKeys= new ArrayList<com.googlecode.objectify.Key<DeviceInfo>>(); 
    for (AlertSubscription s: filteredSubscriptions.values()) 
    {
        dKeys.add(new com.googlecode.objectify.Key<DeviceInfo>(DeviceInfo.class,s.user));

    }
    log.info("Getting keys " + filteredSubscriptions.size());
    Map<com.googlecode.objectify.Key<DeviceInfo>, DeviceInfo> fetched = ofy.get(dKeys);
    log.info("Got keys, looping now");
...
   @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
   public class DeviceInfo {
      @PrimaryKey
      @Persistent
      @Indexed
      private Key key;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved it for me:

```
ObjectifyOpts opts = new ObjectifyOpts();
opts.setConsistency(Consistency.EVENTUAL);
Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin(opts);
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/objectify-appengine/1dIi-JOK_k4